# Can not update Python and other software

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, update-manager, python3

I am updating my Python and can not get through.
The systems suggest using sudo apt-get -f install, however, it does not work either.
How can I solve this issue?

```
$sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-update-manager update-manager
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3-update-manager update-manager
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 59 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/574 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 405655 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-update-manager_1%3a16.04.4_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-update-manager.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-update-manager.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-update-manager_1%3a16.04.4_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-update-manager.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-update-manager.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../update-manager_1%3a16.04.4_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/update-manager.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/update-manager.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/update-manager_1%3a16.04.4_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/update-manager.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/update-manager.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-update-manager_1%3a16.04.4_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/update-manager_1%3a16.04.4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: How fresh is this install?  How long have you run it since installing the OS?

Comment: About 2 months.  I recently need Python 3 and tried to update it. Thank you James.

Comment: Try updating and upgrading your current repository and libraries.  Run: `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade`, `sudo apt install python3`.

Comment: doesn't work.....sudo apt install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.5.1-3).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 update-manager : Depends: update-manager-core (= 1:16.04.3) but 1:16.04.4 is to be installed
 update-manager-core : Depends: python3-update-manager (= 1:16.04.4) but 1:16.04.3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to update your repositories, then the system files.  Then perform a `reinstall of python3`.

*(The `$` represents the command prompt you see in the terminal screen.  The command is what follows the `$` prompt.):*

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install python3-minimal
$ sudo apt install --reinstall python3
```

Then from there add some of the other packages you might need from the repository.  You can get a list of the default repository packages with:

```
$ apt-cache search "^python3" | less
```

Comment: @muru Thanks!  I removed the wild card.  Do you see any problem with purging the flawed install of `python3` which continues prompt that it's already installed and will not take the upgrade?  It's also giving errors about missing default commands line `py3clean`.

Comment: Problem is, `python3` itself doesn't contain much: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/python3/filelist I doubt reinstalling it will help. `python3-minimal` might be of more importance.

Comment: Also see: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/282/158442

Comment: Thanks.  I had thought python2.7 was the default and python3 was an upgraded alternative.  I'll add the `python3-minimal` to the answer.

Comment: @L.D.James Your answer says `python3-minimul` but I think you meant `python3-minimal`?

Comment: @edwinksl You're quiet right!  Thanks for the catch and nudge.